# dojo - click event in template does not work

Tags: templates, events, dojo, widget, click

in a template based widget, I have a table in a template. The table’s body will be constructed 
In my widget using domConstruct. the problem is that The click event of “a” element
does not work. Actully nothing happens when I click on it and the logging does not show any error or massage.( the other click events in My template work fine) the problem only is with this event that is made using domConstruct programmatically. (it is possible that i should parse the "a" elemet?if it is right i do not know how to do it.)

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.features.length; i++) {  
  domConstruct.place(lang.replace('<tr><td><a class="zoomto" data-dojo-attach-   event="ondijitclick:zoomto">{t0}</a></td><td>{t1}</td><td>{t2}</td><td>{t3}</td></tr>',{
  t0:i + 1,
  t1:result.features[i].attributes.rent,
  t2:result.features[i].attributes.OBJECTID,
  t3:result.features[i].attributes.ACCT
}), this.rowNode);

}


…..

zoomto: function () {       
  console.log("zoomto is clicked ");
},
```

Comment: Yes. You need to parse the `<a>` element. `lang.replace` is only for string substitution. The event will be attached after parsing. Or you can also use `dojo/on` module to attach events. In that case no parsing would be required.

Comment: Thanks Himansh. can you tell me how to change the code? i changed my codes but nothing happened again.  the new codes:

Comment: Please share your updated code.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < result.features.length; i++) {
    
  
domConstruct.place(lang.replace('<tr><td><a class="zoomto" id ="zoomID" >{t0}</a></td><td>{t1}</td><td>{t2}</td><td>{t3}</td></tr>',{
t0:i + 1,
t1:result.features[i].attributes.rent,
t2:result.features[i].attributes.OBJECTID,
t3:result.features[i].attributes.ACCT
}), this.rowNode);

}

zoomto: function () {
  
  console.log("zoomto is clicked ");
   
 },

postCreate: function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);             
 on(dom.byId("zoomID"), 'click', lang.hitch(this, this._zoomto));
  
   
 } ,

Comment: it shows codes very messy

Comment: you told event will be attached after parsing . does it means i need to parsing? how should i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to either parse the `<a>` element or attach event using `dojo/on`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.features.length; i++) {  
  var element= domConstruct.toDom(lang.replace('<tr><td><a class="zoomto" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:zoomto">{t0}</a></td><td>{t1}</td><td>{t2}</td><td>{t3}</td></tr>',{
  t0:i + 1,
  t1:result.features[i].attributes.rent,
  t2:result.features[i].attributes.OBJECTID,
  t3:result.features[i].attributes.ACCT
}));
domConstruct.place(element, this.rowNode);

}
dojo.parser.parse(this.rowNode);
```

OR

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.features.length; i++) {  

  var element= domConstruct.toDom(lang.replace('<tr><td><a class="zoomto" >{t0}</a></td><td>{t1}</td><td>{t2}</td><td>{t3}</td></tr>',{
  t0:i + 1,
  t1:result.features[i].attributes.rent,
  t2:result.features[i].attributes.OBJECTID,
  t3:result.features[i].attributes.ACCT
}));
dojo.on(element, 'ondijitclick', this.zoomto);
domConstruct.place(element, this.rowNode);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Himanshu. when i parse the <a> element the way you mentioned, again nothing happen.and with dojo/on, i encounter with some errors.I prefer the first one - parsing  a element, but as i told ,nothing happen when i  changed my codes.